# how to create Directory under sub folder?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

is there any way to create Directory inside the folders of our root Directory ?

for example
`/var/www/test` is my current root directory and `/var/www/test/newDir` the newDir is the Directory wherein I want to create directory and files.

i have tried this but got errors

```
<cffunction name="logError">
    <cfargument name="path" required="true" />
    <cfset var new_logDir = arguments.path />
    <cfset var q = new_logDir/#DateFormat(Trim(Now()),"dd-mm-yyyy")# />
    <cfdirectory action="create" directory="#q#" mode="775" />
</cffunction>
<cfset logDir = ExpandPath("./logger/") />
<cfset logError(logDir) />
```

I am trying to create new directory with today's date as the name of folder inside the logger directory which is the sub directory of my root directory `test`.
Thanks.

Comment: *RE: tried this but got errors* Just saying "something failed to work" does not tell us much of anything ;-) Error messages provide valuable clues about the cause of the issue. It is one more tool others can use to help you find a solution to your question. So it behooves you to always include any error messages with your post.

Comment: Is it relevent that your function is named logs and your code is calling a function named logError?

Answer (score 2):

From your above example you may be having issues because of this line

`<cfset var q = new_logDir/#DateFormat(Trim(Now()),"dd-mm-yyyy")# />`

should be

`<cfset var q = new_logDir & DateFormat(Trim(Now()),"dd-mm-yyyy") & "/" />`

Comment: yeah i correct it... but i want to create folder with today's date as its name in the folder /var/www/test/logs..... logs is inside the root the root... i am not a able to figure out how to create folders inside sub folders in our root folder.

Comment: if you're passing in your logs folder as `arguments.path` then it will work. Are you getting a permissions error?

Comment: so in your example there is already a folder in your root named "logger" correct? and you would like to create the folder "{site_root}/logger/16-01-2014/". What error is it returning?

Comment: now it works i figure out. `<cfset new_logDir = ExpandPath("./logger/") />
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#new_logDir#/#DateFormat(Trim(Now()),"dd-mm-yyyy")#" mode="775" />`.